# SharePoint Available Icons

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In the JSON code to format a SharePoint header you can specify an icon to be used. Does anyone know where the list of usable icons can be found?

The code below allows for the select of an icon and defaults to group:

"iconName": "Group"

What other icons are available and is there a place that lists the available icon names?

Answer (score 0):

These icons reference from the Microsoft Flient UI Icons and Microsoft provide a nice tool to help you find the one you want.

[Home - Fluent UI (microsoft.com)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/styles/web/icons)

[image]

Quick view of all icons: https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/?help=1

Answer (score 0):

As per the Microsoft official documentation of [SharePoint JSON formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#predefined-icons),

> You can use predefined icons from Fluent UI in SharePoint JSON formatting. For details, see the [Fluent UI website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/styles/web/icons).

Answer (score 0):

There is a better place if you are looking for all the SVG and PNG icons. [hTWOo Icons](https://lab.n8d.studio/htwoo/htwoo-core/patterns/design-tokens-icon-overview/design-tokens-icon-overview.rendered.html) as part of the [hTWOo Fluent UI Framework](https://lab.n8d.studio/htwoo/), as all the official new icons are included.

There are two different variants, meanwhile. The filled and the regular version.

You will also find those in their REPO. https://github.com/n8design/htwoo/tree/main/packages/htwoo-icons

[image: Fluent UI Icons Screenshots]